# Wordpress custom loop problem

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Events Manager in wordpress.

I have to display current month events in home page, for that I am using below code.

```
get_row(“SELECT * FROM chip_em_events WHERE event_category_id=’2′ AND event_id=’4′”, ARRAY_A);
echo “”;
echo “$row2[event_name]“;
echo “$row2[event_notes]“;
?>
```

I can get only on event_name and event_notes where id=”4″ but i need to display all events under event_category_id=’2′ for current month.

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you ask for "AND event_id=’4′", if you want other IDs, don't ask for a specific one ;)